# What is the difference between these function callings?

Tags: javascript

So I was wondering what is the difference between these:

```
var a=5;
var b=3;

function asd(a,b) {
   a=a+b;
   b=b-a;
}

function asd2(){
   a=a+b;
   b=b-a;
}

function asd3(var a, var b){
   a=a+b;
   b=b-a;
}
```

Sorry for the lame question, but didn't know how to google is :S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the first takes the parameters from the function arguments,

the second takes the global defined vars.

the third should not work.

Comment: but how does the first affect the a,b variables?

Comment: it simply does not consider the global variables.

Comment: if you call the first function without parameters you get 2 undefined values

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't a homework question, but I'll point you in the right direction.

What is the output of:

```
asd(123,456);
```

Can you change the output of

```
asd2();
```

if so, how?

to tell the difference between asd() and asd3()
try this:

```
var c=10;
var d=4;
alert (asd(c,d));
alert ("c is " + c + " and d is " + d);
```

versus

```
var c=10;
var d=4;
alert(asd3(c,d));
alert ("c is " + c + " and d is " + d);
```

Comment: no this is not a homework... I'm trying to write scripts for fun